# Integration of $\sin(nx)\cos(mx)$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

How do I integrate the following:
$\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(nx)\cos(mx)\,dx$

Thanks,
I am really stuck.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Use properties of definite integral 
$$f(-x)=f(x) \Rightarrow \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$$
$$f(-x)=-f(x) \Rightarrow \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=0$$

Answer (score 4):

The [prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)/[Werner](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#The_identities) useful to know here is
$$ 2\sin{a}\cos{b} = \sin{(a+b)}+\sin{(a-b)} $$
So in this case,
$$ \sin{nx}\cos{mx} = \frac{1}{2}\big( \sin{(n+m)x}+\sin{(n-m)x} \big), $$
which is easy to integrate: assuming that $n,m$ are positive integers, if $n \neq m$, you find
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin{nx}\cos{mx} \, dx = -\frac{1}{2}\left[ \frac{\cos{(n+m)x}}{n+m}+\frac{\cos{(n-m)x}}{n-m} \right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} = 0, $$
since $\cos{ax}$ is an even function, so the values of the RHS at the endpoints are the same. On the other hand, if $n=m$ the second term is not present in the prosthapharesis formula, and you just have
$$ 2\sin{nx}\cos{nx} = \sin{2nx}, $$
and the integral is zero again, since
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin{nx}\cos{nx} \, dx = -\frac{1}{2n}(\cos{2n\pi}-\cos{2n\pi}) = 0. $$

Answer (score 1):

for $m\neq 0$ it i odd function thus answer is $0$ and for $n=0$ easily integer will give answer equal zero.
$\sin{(-nx)}\cos{(-mx)}=-\sin{(nx)}\cos{(mx)}$

Comment: I need more that that - ie how do you convert it into something that you can integrate by using trig functions etc?

Comment: see here, if you still need help, just say http://home.hiram.edu/physics/PHYS350/Odd_Even_Integrals.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do the indefinite integral is this
$$
\int \underbrace{\sin(nx)}_{\displaystyle u} \Big(\underbrace{\cos(nx)\,dx}_{\dfrac{du} n}\Big) = \frac 1 n \int u\,du = \frac 1 n\cdot \frac{u^2} 2 +\text{constant} = \frac{\sin^2(nx)}{2n} +\text{constant}
$$
and then of course you plug in the bounds $-\pi$ and $\pi$ and then subtract.

However, in this case there's a simple way to do it even if you cannot find the indefinite integral.  You need to remember that $\underbrace{\sin(-\theta) = -\sin\theta}_\text{odd}$ and $\underbrace{\cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta}_\text{even}$.
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\pi}^0 \sin(nx)\cos(nx)\,dx + \int_0^\pi \sin(nx)\cos(nx)\,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_\pi^0 -\sin(nw)\cos(nw)\,(-dw) + \int_0^\pi \sin(nx)\cos(nx)\,dx \\
& \qquad\text{where } w = -x \\[12pt]
= {} & \int_\pi^0 \sin(nw)\cos(nw)\,dw + \int_0^\pi \sin(nx)\cos(nx)\,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & - \int_0^\pi \sin(nw)\cos(nw)\,dw + \int_0^\pi \sin(nx)\cos(nx)\,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & 0\text{ because the two integrals are the same.}
\end{align}
When you use the second method, there is no need to find the antiderivative.